# Ubuntu 17.10 lenovo X230 wireless adapter not recognized after reinstall

Tags: 17.10, lenovo, intel-wireless

I had a working install of 17.10 on my X230, but then needed to reinstall the OS - I did not wipe the drive and start over, I reinstalled to repair.

I reinstalled 17.10 from a flash USB drive, and, during the install, opted to connect to the internet for updates - the OS on the flash drive did connect to the internet via wireless.

However, after the re-install (which seems to have gon very well) rebooting and NOT using the flash USB drive, the wireless adapter is not recognized.  I am typing this connected via Ethernet.

At a terminal, running

:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

I get

lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]

I have checked on the UEFI options, and secure boot is set to OFF.

Again,

Same laptop, used to work, nominally the same OS, now wireless works when booted from the flash drive, but not from the hard drive.

Thanks!

EDIT:--------------------
running

$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi

returned nothing.

Comment: What is the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` Please edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I'll run the command and edit in a second.  But first, I ran apt update and apt upgrade and rebooted, and joy.  I am certain that I opted to have the re-install process connect to the internet, and even explicitly entered the password.

Comment: So, you are all set? Fixed??

Comment: Yes!  Thanks!  is there some way for me to explicitly close an item?